# Matplotlib only responds to events from last window drawn

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a button in matplotlib that closes all other plot windows.  I understand the primitives necessary `plt.close(fig)` .  When the following example code is run, only figure2 responds to events.  What am I doing wrong?

I created a gist showing the behavior I encountered.
https://gist.github.com/paddymul/38cd010f81a66793827254b7e6a0f0fe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the [`matplotlib.widgets.Button`](http://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.Button) documentation:

> For the button to remain responsive you must keep a reference to it.

In your script you overwrite the `button` variable containing the first button with the second button. So you loose the reference to the first button.

Calling the first button `button1` and the second `button2` solves the problem.

Comment: Instead of writing *thanks*, consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer (such that it will not stay unsolved) and upvoting it, if you find it useful.